# How do I get the coordinates of an application window running in foreground on Mac using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron, nw.js

I am writing a node.js script that will run on a Mac computer. I'd like to get the coordinates of the application running in the foreground and process details.

For example, if I run the script and the only program I have open is Google Chrome then I should get an array with 1 object containing:

- Google Chrome's process ID
- the x/y coordinates of the Google Chrome window.

So far all I have been able to do is get the list of running process:

- [ps-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node): A process lookup utility

If it helps, I will also be using the [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) framework to run my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`NodObjC`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC) - the Node.js ⇆ Objective-C bridge:

```
var $ = require('nodobjc')

$.framework('Foundation');
$.framework('Cocoa');

var pool = $.NSAutoreleasePool('alloc')('init');
var result = $.CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo($.kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements |
                                          $.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,
                                          $.kCGNullWindowID);
var windowList = $.CFBridgingRelease(result);

var error = $.alloc($.NSError).ref();

var jsonData = $.NSJSONSerialization('dataWithJSONObject', 
                                     windowList, 
                                     'options',
                                     $.NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted,
                                     'error', 
                                     error);

var jsonString = $.NSString('alloc')('initWithData', 
                                     jsonData, 
                                     'encoding',                                          
                                     $.NSUTF8StringEncoding);

var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(parsed);

pool('drain');
```

Comment: Whoa, that's cool. Didn't think of this. Let me try this out and report back.

Sort of related question: if I now wanted to extend this functionality to a Windows 7+, how would I do this? `NodObjC` probably does not work on Windows.

Comment: On Windows try to call `FindWindow` from `user.dll` - https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi